# Issues with mail() function

Tags: php, function, email

Mail is not getting sent to the receiver email.  Please explain what is wrong with the below code that is causing it not to be sent.

**MAIL FORM** (html)

```
    <h1>Send Us Your Feedback!</h1>
<form action="send_mail.php" method="post">
<table>
<tr>
<td>Email Adress:</td>
<td>
<input type="text" name="email_from" value="" maxlength="100" />
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Artist id:</td>
<td>
<textarea rows="10" cols="50" name="artist_id"></textarea>
</td>
</tr>
<tr><td>&nbsp;</td>
<td>
<input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</td>
</tr>
</table>
</form>
```

**SEND MAIL** (php)

```
    <?php
/*
This first bit sets the email address that you want the form to be submitted to.
You will need to change this value to a valid email address that you can access.
*/
$webmaster_email = "berndamian@gmail.com";

/*
This bit sets the URLs of the supporting pages.
If you change the names of any of the pages, you will need to change the values here.
*/
$feedback_page = "feedback_form.html";
$error_page = "error_message.html";
$thankyou_page = "thank_you.html";

/*
This next bit loads the form field data into variables.
If you add a form field, you will need to add it here.
*/
$message = $_REQUEST['Advertiser email: $email_from \n Artist id: $artist_id '] ;
$email_from = $_REQUEST['email_from'] ;
$artist_id = $_REQUEST['artist_id'] ;

/*
The following function checks for email injection.
Specifically, it checks for carriage returns - typically used by spammers to inject a CC list.
*/
function isInjected($str) {
    $injections = array('(\n+)',
    '(\r+)',
    '(\t+)',
    '(%0A+)',
    '(%0D+)',
    '(%08+)',
    '(%09+)'
    );
    $inject = join('|', $injections);
    $inject = "/$inject/i";
    if(preg_match($inject,$str)) {
        return true;
    }
    else {
        return false;
    }
}

// If the user tries to access this script directly, redirect them to the feedback form,
if (!isset($_REQUEST['email_from'])) {
header( "Location: $feedback_page" );
}

// If the form fields are empty, redirect to the error page.
elseif (empty($email_from) || empty($artist_id)) {
header( "Location: $error_page" );
}

// If email injection is detected, redirect to the error page.
elseif ( isInjected($email_from) ) {
header( "Location: $error_page" );
}

// If we passed all previous tests, send the email then redirect to the thank you page.
else {
mail( "$webmaster_email", "FEEDBACK FOR AN ARTIST",
  $message, "From: $email_from" );
header( "Location: $thankyou_page" );
}
?>
```

Comment: I would advise you to use PHPMailer instead of the built-in mail function of PHP. https://github.com/Synchro/PHPMailer

Comment: What exactly the error? The built in PHP mail function is slightly goofy and so we are going to need specifics to really help you out? Is the script not returning anything but the email is not making it?

Comment: @Pieter i have tried PHPMailer but its not working, i don't know how to set it up or configure it, with my hosting details, like smtp e.t.c

Comment: it gets sent to the receiver email, but the message is not sent (i.e, the email, and the artist id) only the header [FEEDBACK FOR AN ARTIST] and the email address field get sent, but this message is not sent (  $message = $_REQUEST['Advertiser email: $email_from \n Artist id: $artist_id '] ;  )

Comment: @dm03514 pls i don't understand what you mean by mail server

Answer (score 2):

This is will come up as an undefined index. You do not need to wrap this in $_REQUEST.

```
$message = $_REQUEST['Advertiser email: $email_from \n Artist id: $artist_id '] ;
```

Move it after you set the email from and artist id, and just make it a string.

```
$message = "Advertiser email: $email_from \n Artist id: $artist_id" ;
```

Comment: with the above, the mail dosen't get sent at all

Comment: everything works fine just that i get this as the message of the mail{Advertiser email: $email_from \n Artist id: $artist_id} instead of this for example {advertiser email: mail@example.com -line break- Artist id: yopu} pls help  me

Answer (score 0):

change to `mail($webmaster_email,"FEEDBACK FOR AN ARTIST",$message,"FROM:".$email_from);`

Comment: i want the artist id, and email address to be in the message area, because i might add other inputs to the form later on, so that the details will be sent as a message

Comment: `$message = $_REQUEST['Advertiser email: $email_from \n Artist id: $artist_id '] ;` this line must be `$message = $_REQUEST['Advertiser email'].$email_from.'\nArtist id: '.$artist_id ;` I'm really not sure about your code, seems messed up, from where do you get the `Advertiser email` parameter?

Comment: the above is not clear to me, pls do you mind editing it pls, i want the body of the message sent to the email to look like this {advertiser email: mail@example.com -line break- Artist id: yopu} that is all, i might add more fields later on.

Comment: the advertiser email is $email_from ------ and the artist id is $artist_id

Comment: Remove the `$message` line and add `$message = "Advertiser email: ".$email_from."\r\nArtist id: ".$artist_id;` after `$artist_id` line..should work. And as far as I know you can only send email using example@yourdomain.com and not @gmail.com

Comment: after using your above suggestion, every thing works fine, but am getting this as the message of the email [Advertiser email:
Artist id:]

Comment: Sorry my bad, try replacing `$message = 'Advertiser email: '.$email_from.'\r\nArtist id: '.$artist_id;`

Comment: Your parameters are empty I guess, can you edit your question and post the edited version of the files?